# How can I estimate parameters (variance) of a linear model with dual error terms using the log mle?

Tags: r, excel, matlab, eviews

[image: The Linear model with composite error terms]

The log likelihood function is then given by:

`lnL(α,β,σ_v,σ_u )=-Tln(σ)+T/2  ln⁡(2⁄π)+∑[lnΦ((s.ε_it λ)/σ)-1/2 (ε_it/σ)^2 ]` [image: The Log likelihood function in picture]

Where T is the number of time periods,`σ=√(σ_u^2+σ_v^2 ) , λ=σ_u/σ_v.`

```
S = -1 for Undervaluation Model
S = 1 for Overvaluation Model
```

Comment: I have add pictures of the models for a better view.